# Tracker options beyond bug\feature\support

Tags: redmine

Is there a way to mark issues with different options than the default Bug\Feature\Support options in Redmine under the "Tracker" field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, you may define your own [trackers in redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineIssueTrackingSetup): `Administration -> Trackers` lists all existing trackers and lets you add new ones.